# Lazy filter for one element

Tags: scala

I'm refactoring some scala code to teach my coworkers about for-comprehensions, and I've got a line like:

```
for {
  // ...
  result <- components.collectFirst({ case section if section.startsWith(DESIRED_SUBSTRING) => section.substring(section.indexOf(DELIM) + 1).trim() == "true" })
} yield result
```

That's a bit long.

At first, I wished I could just skip the `result <- ...` followed by the immediate `yield`, as I can in Haskell, but then I noticed the processing going on inside `collectFirst`.

So I thought it'd be much easier to read as I should better do this as

```
for {
  // ...
  section <- components.filter(_.startsWith(DESIRED_SUBSTRING)).headOption
} yield section.substring(section.indexOf(DELIM) + 1).trim() == "true"
```

Which works, but it is less efficient, since `filter` has to process all the elements.  I'd like to be able to use a lazy filter:

```
components.withFilter(_.startsWith(DESIRED_SUBSTRING)).headOption
```

But `FilterMonadic` doesn't seem to support `headOption`, and I can't figure out a way to derive it from the operations it does support. I'm sure there's a way with `flatMap` and some `bf`, but I'm too unfamiliar with the scala ecosystem at the moment.

If I want to stick with standard library tricks, am I stuck with

```
for {
  // ...
  section <- components.collectFirst({ case section if section.startsWith(DESIRED_SUBSTRING) => section })
} yield section.substring(section.indexOf(DELIM) + 1).trim() == "true"
```

Or is there something better I can use?

Comment: Wouldn't `find` do what you want?

Comment: Eduardo: This is what I get for not knowing the API. :) Make it an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: For that line, what you've done is the "best" approach in terms of wanting to use a for-comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `components.find(_.startsWith(DESIRED_SUBSTRING))` that will give you an `Option` with the first element that meets the condition. Then, you can just `map` over it with any subsequent processing you need.